# How to populate old values in search field after searching in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I have a search form 
View file:

```
 <td>Product</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data[Search][product]" value="<?php echo $oldData['Search']['product'];?>"></td>
                <td>Product type</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data[Search][product_type]"></td>
                <td>Growing Practice</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="organic" />Organic<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="ecological" />Ecological<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="ipm" />IPM<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="bio_dynamic" />Bio-Dynamic<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="conventional" />Conventional<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][growing_method][]" value="other" />Other
                </td>
                <td>Ugly</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Search][ugly]" value="y" /><br>
                <td>Miles</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="data[Search][miles]" id="search_mile"></td>
                <td>from</td>
                <td>Zip</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data[Search][zip]" id="search_zip"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" id="search_post">Search</button> </td>
```

After clicking on the search button the search takes place but I need the submitted values to stay  back in the form so the user can see what they have searched on.
In controller I tried to the values as we set it.

```
$this->set('oldDatas',$this->request->data);
```

But I was not able to get it in the view from the following code.

```
 <td><input type="text" name="data[Search][product]" value="<?php echo $oldData['Search']['product'];?>"></td>
```

I searched a log but was not able to get the desired result.
Is there a way to populate the values back in the form after submitting.
If anyone have any idea about it please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the data in a PHP session variable.  Cake has a session component where you can write to variables.  You can use the Session Helper to set the value of the input in the view.

Controller:

```
$this->Session->write('product', $this->request->data['Search']['product']);
```

View:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="data[Search][product]" value="<?= $this->Session->read('product') ?>">
</td>
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html